# Database type session driver in Laravel not working as expected

Tags: laravel, session

I am using the database-type session driver in Laravel Let for example a user logs in using the Chrome browser, and the record of his session is getting stored inside the session table but if I try to visit the same website using any other browser, it automatically authenticating the user.

If I try to open the website in another system, it also takes automatic authentication even though the user has not logged in once.
[session table in workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkqWO.png)
[.env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1TDZ.png)

When I was using the file-type session driver it was working properly.

I wanted that the user should not to get automatically authenticated, since it making authenticate with the wrong credential to a wrong user

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's database session driver stores session data in a database table and uses cookies to maintain session state. If a user logs in using one browser or device, the session cookie will be stored in their browser, and if they switch to another browser or device, they will be automatically authenticated due to the cookie.

To require users to log in with their credentials every time they switch browsers or devices, change the "same_site" option in your Laravel session configuration file to **"strict"** or **"lax"**. This will prevent the session cookie from being sent to the server when the user navigates from a different site or browser.

Here's an example:

```
'same_site' => 'strict',
```

More info:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#configuring-the-session

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I have changed the 'same_site' => 'strict', but its still working the same. I also have run the command "php artisan config:clear" & "php artisan config:cache" after making the changes.